# How to Bind Html 5 Video Controls attribute in Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I need to conditionally emit html 5 controls attribute in Knockout. I meann some time I emit controls and sometime does not. The attr binding will not work? Is there is any thing that make it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `attr binding` you just need to return `null` or `undefined` from your observable then KO won't emit the given attribute:

```
<video id="movie" width="320" height="240" 
       data-bind="attr: {controls: enableControls}">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<button data-bind="{click: click}" >Add/Remove Controls </button>
```

And on your viewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
  var self = this;
  self.enableControls = ko.observable(true);
  self.click = function()
  {
    if (self.enableControls())
      self.enableControls(null);
    else
      self.enableControls(true);
  }

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALHFW/).

Comment: @user960567 strange... it works for me on multiple machines (tested with IE and Chrome). Is the provided description and sample not enough for you? I can extend my answer if you tell me which part is not clear for you?

Comment: I want to check your JSFiddle Html/Js/Css. Currently the link does not show any thing.

Comment: @user960567 I've copied all the code from the fiddle to my answer.